# Android - How to get all items in a Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, items

How do I get all items in a Spinner?

I was having trouble trying to search a way to get all items from a `Spinner`but I was not able to find an elegant solution. The only solution seems to be storing the items list before to add it to the `Spinner`

Is there another better way to do this?

Comment: Write custom adapter. In adapter add method that returns item list...

Comment: I have no control over the adapter. I am just receiving the Spinner in my method and I just know the kind of Class of the items

Comment: `List<MyModel> items = ((CastMyAdapterType)mySpinner.getAdapter()).getList();`

Comment: I cannot find this method in `android.widget.Adapter` neither in `android.widget.SpinnerAdapter`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A simple and elegant way to do this is, if you know the objects type that the spinner is storing:

```
public class User {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    /** Getters and Setters **/

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Given the previous class and a `Spinner` that contains a list of `User` you can do the following:

```
public List<User> retrieveAllItems(Spinner theSpinner) {
    Adapter adapter = theSpinner.getAdapter();
    int n = adapter.getCount();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        User user = (User) adapter.getItem(i);
        users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
}
```

This helped me! I hope it would do it for you!