# Android: Create ArrayList from Spinner programmatically

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

I have a spinner, created in an XML file:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/unitSpinner"
    android:entries="@array/units" />
```

With its entries defined in `array.xml`

```
<string-array name="units">
    <item>g</item>
    <item>kg</item>
    <item>ml</item>
    <item>l</item>
    <item>szt.</item>
    <item>op.</item>
</string-array>
```

Now in my Java file I want to create an `ArrayList<String>` which contents after feeding it with `Spinner`'s entries would be:

```
["g", "kg", "ml", "l", "szt.", "op."]
```

My Java code looks like this:

```
Spinner unit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unitSpinner);
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
//pass information from unit to array
```

### EDIT:

This question differs from many questions like [Android : Fill Spinner From Java Code Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920754/android-fill-spinner-from-java-code-programmatically) as I don't want to fill Spinner with an Array, but the opposite way.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: Do you mean something like that [Change String-Array in Strings.xml to ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127071/change-string-array-in-strings-xml-to-arraylist/19127223) ?

Comment: @user141080 this question is helpful, but please check out my edited Java code: I would like to pass entries from my Spinner object to the ArrayList<String> object

Comment: @koman900 take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127374/android-how-to-get-all-items-in-a-spinner

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You already know exactly what those values are. What is the point of building an `ArrayList` from the `Spinner` values?

Comment: @MikeM. e.g. you get a `String unit` from other function. Then you want to make this unit selected in the `Spinner` using `spinner.setSelection(int index)`. You need to know what is the index of `String unit` in the `Spinner`. My other functions allow you to programatically add or edit the values in `Spinner` so reading an `ArrayList` from `array.xml` doesn't do the job.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. You should've mentioned in the question that the `Spinner`'s values are editable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the list from the XML array directly. no need to get ti from the spinner

```
String[] ss  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.units);
ArrayList<String> array = Arrays.asList(words);
```

if this aproach does not work with you you can  try to get all the items fom the spinner via loop

```
    for( int i = 0  ; i< unit.getAdapter().getCount() ; i++ ){
                array.add ( ss.getAdapter().getItem( i ) )

}
```

Hope this will help.